# Parsing dates with d3.js v.4

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to learn how to code with the d3.js by working on my first d3 [mini project](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/visualize-data-with-a-bar-chart) based on the Free Code Camp curriculum. I am trying to make a simple bar graph with this [json file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json). I got stuck trying to format the dates in the file. I've tried looking at the [d3.js API](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#timeFormat) and I am still lost. I would be very grateful for any advice that comes my way. Here is my code

```
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//then make a function to parse the time
var parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0],0.5);

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


//setup axis


// get the data
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json").get(function(error,dataset){
  var d =dataset.data;
  d.forEach(function(datum, i) {
        d[0]=parseDate(datum[0]);
         //console.log(datum[1]);
    });
  //console.log(d[3][0]);

});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want `timeParse`, not `timeFormat`:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
```

Using [timeParse](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#timeParse),

> the returned function parses a specified string, returning the corresponding date or null if the string could not be parsed according to this format’s specifier.

And this is how your `forEach` function should be:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d[0] = parseDate(d[0]);
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json", function(json) {

    var data = json.data;

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d[0] = parseDate(d[0]);
    });
  
    console.log(data);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I use timeParse because I want to convert a string into a time. And I use timeFormat when I want to convert a time into a string?

Comment: Basically, yes, but you can use timeFormat to set the specifier for timeParse, like this: `var myFormat = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"); var parseDate = d3.timeParse(myFormat);`

Comment: @user3426338 don't forget to pay attention to the `forEach` function: compare yours and mine, to understand why yours didn't work.

Comment: Thank you! Also you wouldn't happen to know good resources to learn more about d3 scales and axes? The wiki is kind of dense for me.

Comment: yeah. I figured it out. its suppose to be d[i] = parseDate(d[0]); I was only getting the first date element  and not all of them in the original code

Comment: @user3426338 I really like Scott Murray's book. It's basic and very didactic (free online): http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345